# Spring MVC + Hibernate 4 + Spring Security

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, spring-security

I have been struggling to make all of this work since days now and don't know what to do. I believe I went through every single post on the subject here on SO and went through douzens of tutorials...

Here is the message I am having at this time:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'fruitController': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire method: public void com.controller.FruitController.setFruitManager(com.service.FruitManager); nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No matching bean of type [com.service.FruitManager] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {}
```

I have been able to solve this error in the past, but only to have a new one "No session found for current thread". When not having this one, I got some problem with my Assembler and UserDetailsServiceImpl bean not being recognized in my spring-security.xml file...

I do not think the problem(s) come from my code, I just can't get to set my config files properly and I am probably missing something here.

Here are the config files:

web.xml:

```
<web-app id="WebApp_ID" version="2.4"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee 
    http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd">

    <display-name>Spring MVC Application</display-name>

    <!-- Spring MVC -->
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>
            /WEB-INF/mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml,
            /WEB-INF/spring-security.xml
        </param-value>
    </context-param>

    <!-- Spring Security -->
    <filter>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
    </filter>

    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>

</web-app>
```

applicationContext.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop 
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.0.xsd
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx 
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.0.xsd">

    <context:annotation-config/>
    <!-- Load everything except @Controllers -->
    <context:component-scan base-package="com">
        <context:exclude-filter expression="org.springframework.stereotype.Controller"
            type="annotation" />
    </context:component-scan>

    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />

    <tx:advice id="txAdvice">
        <tx:attributes>
            <tx:method name="save*" />
            <tx:method name="*" read-only="false" />
        </tx:attributes>
    </tx:advice>

    <bean id="transactionManager"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="sessionFactory"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <property name="annotatedClasses">
            <list>
                <value>com.dao.HibernateFruitDAO</value>
            </list>
        </property>
        <property name="packagesToScan">
            <list>
                <value>com.service</value>
                <value>com.controller</value>
            </list>
        </property>
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="dataSource"
        class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/basename" />
        <property name="username" value="xxx" />
        <property name="password" value="yyy" />
    </bean>

</beans>
```

mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop" xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans     
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd">

    <context:annotation-config />

    <context:property-placeholder location="classpath:hibernate.properties" />

    <!-- Load @Controllers only -->
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.controller"
        use-default-filters="false">
        <context:include-filter expression="org.springframework.stereotype.Controller"
            type="annotation" />
    </context:component-scan>

    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter"></bean>
    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping"></bean>

    <bean
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix">
            <value>/WEB-INF/pages/</value>
        </property>
        <property name="suffix">
            <value>.jsp</value>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="messageSource"
        class="org.springframework.context.support.ResourceBundleMessageSource">
        <property name="basenames">
            <list>
                <value>mymessages</value>
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="propertyConfigurer"
        class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
        <property name="locations">
            <list>
                <value>classpath:jdbc.properties</value>
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>

</beans>
```

spring-security.xml
    
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
                            http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
                            http://www.springframework.org/schema/security http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.1.xsd">

```
    <beans:bean id="userDetailsService" class="com.service.UserDetailsServiceImpl">
    </beans:bean>

    <beans:bean id="assembler" class="com.service.Assembler">
    </beans:bean>


    <http auto-config='true' use-expressions='true'>
        <intercept-url pattern="/login*" access="isAnonymous()" />
        <intercept-url pattern="/secure/**" access="hasRole('ROLE_Admin')" />
            <logout logout-success-url="/listing.htm" />
        <form-login login-page="/login.htm" login-processing-url="/j_spring_security_check"
            authentication-failure-url="/login_error.htm" default-target-url="/listing.htm"
            always-use-default-target="true" />
    </http>

    <beans:bean id="com.daoAuthenticationProvider"
        class="org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider">
        <beans:property name="userDetailsService" ref="userDetailsService" />
    </beans:bean>

    <beans:bean id="authenticationManager"
        class="org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager">
        <beans:property name="providers">
            <beans:list>
                <beans:ref local="com.daoAuthenticationProvider" />
            </beans:list>
        </beans:property>
    </beans:bean>

    <authentication-manager>
        <authentication-provider user-service-ref="userDetailsService">
            <password-encoder hash="plaintext" />
        </authentication-provider>
    </authentication-manager>
</beans:beans>
```

FruitController:

```
package com.controller;

@Controller
public class FruitController{

    protected final Log logger = LogFactory.getLog(getClass());


    private FruitManager fruitManager;

    @Autowired
    public void setFruitManager(FruitManager FruitManager) {
        this.fruitManager = fruitManager;
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/listing", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String getFruits(ModelMap model) {
        model.addAttribute("fruits", this.fruitManager.getFruits());
        return "listing";
    }
}
```

FruitDAO:
    public interface FruitDAO {

```
public List<Fruit> getFruitList();

public List<Fruit> getFruitListByUserId(String userId);

public void saveFruit(Fruitprod);

public void updateFruit(Fruitprod);

public void deleteFruit(int id);

public Fruit getFruitById(int id);
```

}

HibernateFruitDAO

```
package com.dao;

@Repository("fruitDao")
public class HibernateFruitDAO implements FruitDAO {


private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

        @Autowired
        public void setSessionFactory(SessionFactory sessionFactory) {
            this.sessionFactory = sessionFactory;
        }

    public List<Fruit> getList() {
        return (List<Fruit>) getSession().createCriteria ( Fruit.class ).list();
    }

    public List<Fruit> getFruitListByUserId(String userId) {
        return (List<Fruit>)sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createCriteria("from Fruit where userId =?", userId).list();
    }

    public void saveFruit(Fruit fruit) {
        sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().save(fruit);
    }

    public void updateFruit(Fruit fruit) {
        sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().update(fruit);
    }

    public void deleteFruit(int id) {
        Fruit fruit = (Fruit) sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().load(Fruit.class, id);
        if (null != fruit) {
            sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().delete(fruit);
        }
    }

    public Fruit getFruitById(int id) {
        return (Fruit)sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().load(Fruit.class, id);
    }

    private Session getSession(){
            return sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
        }
}
```

Interface FruitManager:

```
package com.service;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.List;

import com.domain.Fruit;


public interface FruitManager extends Serializable{

    public List<Fruit> getFruits();

    public List<Fruit> getFruitsByUserId(String userId);

    public void addFruit(Fruit fruit);

    public void removeFruit(int id);

    public Fruit getFruitById(int id);

    public void updateFruit(Fruit fruit);
}
```

Implementation of FruitManager:

```
package com.service;

@Repository("fruitManager")
@Transactional
public class SimpleFruitManager implements FruitManager {

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = ...;

    @Autowired
    private FruitDAO fruitDao;

    public List<Fruit> getFruits() {
        return fruitDao.getFruitList();
    }

    public List<Fruit> getFruitsByUserId(String userId){
        return fruitDao.getFruitListByUserId(userId);
    }

    public void setFruitDao(FruitDAO fruitDao) {
        this.fruitDao = fruitDao;
    }

    public void addFruit(Fruit fruit) {
        fruitDao.saveFruit(fruit);
    }

    public void removeFruit(int id) {
        fruitDao.deleteFruit(id);
    }

    public  getFruitById(int id) {
        return fruitDao.getFruitById(id);
    }

    public void updateFruit(Fruit fruit) {
        fruitDao.updateFruit(fruit);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At a glance, it seems you're suffering from a common problem of not understanding how Spring ApplicationContexts fit together to make a web application. See my other answer to exactly the same problem to see if it clears things up:

[Declaring Spring Bean in Parent Context vs Child Context](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7746633/declaring-spring-bean-in-parent-context-vs-child-context/7748108#7748108)

You may also be enlightened by this answer on a similar topic, which links to my previously mentioned answer as well as one other:

[Spring XML file configuration hierarchy help/explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7774295/spring-xml-file-configuration-hierarchy-help-explanation/7774597#7774597)

A couple brief tips to get you headed in the right direction...

By convention, Spring's ContextLoaderListener loads beans from `WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml` to create the root application context. When you override the default, as you're doing, that file is no longer loaded.

*Tip #1: stick with the conventional behavior. It'll make your life simpler.*

Also by convention, starting up a Spring DispatcherServlet loads beans from `WEB-INF/<servlet name>-context.xml` to create the context used to configure the dispatcher servlet. This context becomes a child of the root context.

*Tip #2: see tip #1*

So you see, you're presently over-configuring things. Read the linked answers and the reference materials linked therein. Learn to work with Spring instead of against it.

Comment: Thank you for the enlightening answer, that helped me a lot. I think I have cleaned out most of my config files and understood how it works. I have a remaining issue with the spring-security.xml this time: "No bean named 'userDetailsService' is defined". The userDetailsService bean is not found. I did comment the two bean declarations in my spring-security.xml (Assembler and UserDetailsServiceImpl). The reason I did remove them is that they should already be scanned by the root context.

Comment: This answer and the links provided helped me have clean config files that make sense. I also understand way better the way it should work and the way Spring should be used. Very USEFUL answer.

Answer (score 0):

In your web.xml file, the `applicationContext.xml` is never get loaded. You should put it location in `context-param`. Put the location of `mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml` (containing controller related bean) as init-param for DispatcherServlet instead:

```
<init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>/WEB-INF/mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml</param-value>
        </init-param>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you must to use this in the DaoImpl to get the session:

```
@Autowired
private SessionFactory sessionFactory;
```