# No mapping found in DIspatcherServlet

Tags: json, spring, tomcat, spring-mvc

I have been fighting this message for a few days now and cannot figure out what I have wrong.

Basically what I am trying to do is serve up json with my service.  I am not interested in returning a jsp.

The URL I am requesting is

```
localhost/service/products/1
```

Here is the error.

```
WARN - No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/service/products/1] in DispatcherServlet with name 'cr'
```

My ProductsController shows as follows:

```
package com.cr.controllers;

import com.cr.dao.ProductsDao;
import com.cr.entity.Products;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseBody;

import javax.servlet.ServletResponse;
import java.io.IOException;

/**
 * User: ChappleZ
 * Date: 2/17/13
 * Time: 8:21 PM
 */
@Controller
@RequestMapping(value = "/service")
public class ProductsController {
    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ProductsController.class);
    @Autowired
    private ProductsDao productsDao;

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public void get(ServletResponse response) throws IOException {
        response.setContentType("text/plain");
        response.getWriter().print("My Products dao: " + productsDao);
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/products/{productId}",
            headers="Accept=application/json",
            method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public
    @ResponseBody
    Products findByProductId(@PathVariable Long productId) {
        Products products = productsDao.getProductsById(productId);
        return products;
    }
}
```

Application Context:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:jpa="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa"
       xmlns:jdbc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc"
       xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
       xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa/spring-jpa.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc/spring-jdbc-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.0.xsd
       ">
    <context:annotation-config />
    <jpa:repositories base-package="com.cr" />

    <!--   // JPA specific configuration here: dataSource, persistenceUnitManager exceptionTranslator, entityManagerFactory, SessionFactory, transactionManager - should not be relevant for this problem, tell me if i'm wrong-->

    <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor" />

    <bean id="productsDao" class="com.cr.dao.impl.ProductsDaoImpl"/>

    <bean id="entityManagerFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
        <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="spring-jpa"/>
        <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
            <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter">
                <property name="showSql" value="true"/>
                <property name="generateDdl" value="true"/>
                <property name="database" value="MYSQL"/>
            </bean>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
        <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory"/>
    </bean>

    <tx:annotation-driven/>

    <bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" destroy-method="close">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/crcart3"/>
        <property name="username" value="root"/>
        <property name="password" value=""/>
    </bean>
</beans>
```

web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">
    <display-name>cr</display-name>
    <description>cr</description>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>log4jConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>classpath:log4j.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>
            classpath:applicationContext.xml
        </param-value>
    </context-param>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>


    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>cr</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>/WEB-INF/conf/spring-controllers.xml</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>cr</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <filter>
        <filter-name>httpMethodFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter</filter-class>
    </filter>

    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>httpMethodFilter</filter-name>
        <servlet-name>cr</servlet-name>
    </filter-mapping>

    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>15</session-timeout>
    </session-config>

    <error-page>
        <error-code>401</error-code>
        <location>/error/401</location>
    </error-page>
    <error-page>
        <error-code>404</error-code>
        <location>/error/404</location>
    </error-page>
    <error-page>
        <error-code>500</error-code>
        <location>/error/500</location>
    </error-page>
    <error-page>
        <error-code>504</error-code>
        <location>/error/504</location>
    </error-page>
    <error-page>
        <exception-type>java.lang.Throwable</exception-type>
        <location>/error/500</location>
    </error-page>

</web-app>
```

Spring-Controllers.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
       xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
       xmlns:jee="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee"
       xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
       xmlns:oxm="http://www.springframework.org/schema/oxm"
       xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/util http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/oxm http://www.springframework.org/schema/oxm/spring-oxm-3.0.xsd">

    <context:property-placeholder location="classpath:config.properties"/>

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.cr"/>

    <bean id="jsonConverter" class="org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter">
        <property name="supportedMediaTypes" value="application/json"/>
    </bean>

    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter">
        <property name="messageConverters">
            <list>
                <ref bean="jsonConverter"/>
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/"/>

</beans>
```

Also if it helps this is also being shown with the same warning for the 404 page.

```
WARN - No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/service/products/1] in DispatcherServlet with name 'cr'
WARN - No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/error/404] in DispatcherServlet with name 'cr'
```

Comment: You should show the request being sent.

Comment: I updated with the URL I am using. BTW, @RyanStewart your github testbed is awesome. It really helped to get me this far.  I was struggling for two weeks until I found that and it got me this far.

Comment: Not just the URL, the entire request.

Comment: I am using Postman to send my get request to that URL. What do you mean in terms of the entire request?

Comment: The first line would look like `GET /service/products/1 HTTP/1.1`, then there's a bunch of headers. The format is described in the [W3 spec](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec5.html).

Comment: Since I am using Postman (a Chrome REST testing application) I am not having to write out the entire request.   If it helps I am also running into the same issue when doing an ajax call.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/24862/discussion-between-zmanc-and-ryan-stewart)

Comment: It's seem your spring container not scan your controller.Change your scan package with "    <context:component-scan base-package="com.cr.controllers"/>
"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Three problems I see:

1. In the web.xml, your DispatcherServlet should be mapped to `/*` instead of just `/`. The latter only matches the empty path and nothing else, so the path you're requesting never hits the servlet.
2. You left `<mvc:annotation-driven/>` out of your spring-controller.xml.
3. Probably unrelated, but sure to cause future problems, in your spring-controllers.xml, you shouldn't be component-scanning the same base package as you do in the applicationContext.xml. The spring-controllers.xml is for configuring your DispatcherServlet, and should only have controllers and MVC-related beans in it. The applicationContext.xml is where your services, DAOs, and related things should live. It's the same problem as described here:

[Declaring Spring Bean in Parent Context vs Child Context](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7746633/declaring-spring-bean-in-parent-context-vs-child-context/7748108#7748108)

Further explanations of the proper way to configure the Spring contexts in Spring MVC can be found at:

[Why DispatcherServlet creates another application context?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7833767/why-dispatcherservlet-creates-another-application-context/7836031#7836031)